# How to combine nsobject file and nscollectionviewcontroller to viewcontroller in xcode or nscollectionviewcontroller to viewcontroller only

Tags: iphone, xcode, viewcontroller, nsobject, nscollectionview

I am download and use this [Instagram feed here](https://github.com/Busta117/SBInstagram). But i don't want switch more view. In my app touch a instagram feed button then switch a view and then i am doing some view appearance so i want to combine SBInstagramController and SBInstagramCollectionViewController (files in that link) to a ViewController.

If i combine 2 files it's show nearly 10 more error. If i include @property (nonatomic, retain) UICollectionView *collectionView; in viewcontroller.h file there is no error and single collectionview function called it's show empty page with navigation

if 2 file can't combine then at least uicollectionview move into uiviewcontroller

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combination of two file worked for me and only one error occurred(the Difficult one). Just i am create a new collection view in xib and create a IBOutlet for that. That's it worked.. !!!!!